# unable to concatinate two char* into one

Tags: c, string-concatenation

I'm having trouble with creating a function that receives 2 char* and need to return a char* that concatenate the input strings.

```
char* deviceId = "A1B2C3D4";
char* channelUrl = "/arduino/subscribers/";


char* getSubscriberUrl(char* channelUrl, char* deviceId) {
  char* buffer[sizeof(channelUrl) + sizeof(deviceId)+2];
  strcat(buffer, channelUrl);
  strcat(buffer, deviceId);

  return buffer;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
initializing argument 1 of 'char* strcat(char*, const char*)'
 char  *strcat (char *__restrict, const char *__restrict);
                ^~~~~~
sketch_sep13a:87:10: error: cannot convert 'char**' to 'char*' in return
   return buffer;
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: 1. Use `strlen`, not `sizeof`. 2. Use `malloc`, not a local array.  3. Use a modern compiler, with warnings enabled, which would have warned you about #2, and perhaps #1.

Comment: In addition, `char* buffer[sizeof(channelUrl) + sizeof(deviceId)+2];` is an array of pointers to characters, not characters.

Comment: It should be `char buffer[...]` without the `*`.

Comment: The first `strcat()` should be `strcpy()`, because `buffer` isn't null-terminated.

Comment: `buffer` is a local variable with automatic storage duration.  Its lifetime ends when the function returns, which means that returning (a pointer into) it is not useful.  You will need to allocate your buffer dynamically if you want it to live past the return of the function in which it is allocated.

Comment: Not going to sugarcoat it, I'm afraid. Regarding what you did wrong in this code, almost everything.  Your `sizeof` calculations are wrong, the type of `buffer` is wrong (in more ways that one), the opening `strcat` is wrong; it should be a `strcpy`, and  `return  buffer;` returns the base address of an expiring array that will no longer exist after exiting scope from `getSubscriberUrl`.

Comment: `sketch_sep13a` .... are you using the Arduino IDE? If so, you have a C++-ish compiler. It has a `String` type built-in. Use it! `String a = "...."; String b = "...."; String c = a + b;`

Comment: regarding: `char* buffer[sizeof(channelUrl) + sizeof(deviceId)+2];`  this declares an array of pointers, not a char array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `channelUrl` and `deviceId` are pointers, so `sizeof` just returns the size of a pointer, not the lengths of the strings. Use `strlen()`.
2. You only need to add 1 -- there's only 1 null terminator needed for the combined string.
3. `buffer` is uninitialized, so you can't concatenate to it.
4. Instead of using multiple calls to `strcat()`, you can use `sprintf()`.
5. You can't return a local array. You need to allocate the result with `malloc()`.

```
char* getSubscriberUrl(char* channelUrl, char* deviceId) {
  char *buffer = malloc(strlen(channelUrl) + strlen(deviceId)+1);
  sprintf(buffer, "%s%s", channelUrl, deviceId);

  return buffer;
}
```